# ScriptEngine is Null for getEngineByName("JavaScript")?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("JavaScript");
```

engine is null??? Also i try to iterate through the scriptEnginefactories it's zero...

i have js-1.7R1.jar on my classpath...can anyone tell me what i need to do else to register the javascript engine( I found Rhino which is js-1.7r.jar)

Thanks.

Comment: How are you running the class? Through an IDE? If so, is its compiler-level set to Java 1.6 or higher?

Comment: Eclipse uses its own compiler, but uses the system's JRE: you sure your JRE is 1.6+? Do other 1.6 features work? (annotations)

Comment: @BartKiers Thanks! your comments help point me in right direction..in my IDE i had to remove my JRE(it was 1.5) and add it back as 1.6....i recently changed to 1.6 but did not fix that......  thanks , i was stuck for a good while :/

Comment: @Jeryl Cook Can you make that solution official and answer your own question then so that your question can help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Eclipse uses its own compiler, but uses the system's JRE...*" - Bart Kiers

Make sure the JRE is 1.6 or higher. Based on the comments, Jeryl Cook had eclipse set to JRE 1.5. He removed this from inside eclipse and added JRE 1.6 which worked and solved his problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with JDK 11. Using JDK 8 solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have

> sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal, com.sun.script.javascript;

packages in your classpath. 

What you are trying to run is fork version of Rhino within Java SE (Java Scripting Api). It looks like your Java doesn't have it (check above packages).
I believe js-1.7R1.jar is original Rhino implementation from mozilla - you can try to run it directly [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial), not via Java Scripting API.